# SQLite How to Use Generated Columns to do Additional Calculations Within The Same Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm used to the sql syntax in SAS that allows a creation of additional calculations using other generated columns based on agggregate functions. For example:

```
select date(created_at) as date,
       count(distinct case when platform = 'Android' then user_id end) as 
       Android,
       count(distinct case when platform = 'iOS' then user_id end) as iOS,
       calculated Android + calculated iOS as Total
from dataset
group by 1;
```

My question is on the last column 'Total' created above. SAS has a built-in function called 'calculated' that recognizes an already generated column and allows one to use that column to do other calculations.

Does something similar exist in SQLite, or is the sub-query the only other option?

Comment: You can always use a CTE. More readable than subqueries imo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery or CTE in standard SQL:

```
select d.*, (Android + iOS) as Total
from (select date(created_at) as date,
             count(distinct case when platform = 'Android' then user_id end) as Android,
             count(distinct case when platform = 'iOS' then user_id end) as iOS,
      from dataset
      group by date(created_at)
     ) d;
```

The `calculated` keyword is a handy extension in `proc sql`.  However, it is not available in other databases.